# Continuously Export Data From BigQuery To Cloud SQL

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I am currently collecting a large amount of analytical data and storing it in GCS. I'm using BigQuery Scheduled Queries to process this data into useful information and reports. I'm storing the results of these scheduled queries in GCS in parquet format.

I can manually access the results with BigQuery with an External Table. Using the BigQuery API in my applications is far too slow for my Applications API. What would be the best way to schedule & automate exporting this data from BigQuery into Cloud SQL, so I can access to read this data from an API much faster than I can from BigQuery?

Due to the complexity of my application, I have multiple Google Cloud Projects, each with their own services. My BigQuery and Cloud Storage are in one project, and my Cloud SQL servers are in a separate project. Because they are in separate projects, the documented method of [**Connecting BigQuery to Cloud SQL**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/connect-to-sql) doesn't appear to be an option.

Comment: Hi @epool, Could you take a look at this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69918320/data-transfer-from-bq-to-cloud-sql) and the [documentation](https://medium.com/google-cloud/replicate-data-from-bigquery-to-cloud-sql-2b23a08c52b1) which might be helpful for you ? Please let me know if this helped you or not.